# CASE statement and how to use values from it

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have a query

```
select 
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    i.order_item_id,
    max( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id' and i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id THEN im.meta_value END ) as product_id,
    max( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_qty' and i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id THEN im.meta_value END ) as qty,   
    max( CASE WHEN prm.meta_key = '_sku' and im.meta_value = prm.post_id THEN prm.meta_value END ) as sku,
    max( CASE WHEN prm.meta_key = '_regular_price' and im.meta_value = prm.post_id THEN prm.meta_value END ) as product_price
from 
    wp_posts as p,
    wp_postmeta as pm,
    wp_woocommerce_order_items as i,
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as im,
    wp_postmeta as prm    
where 
    p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    and p.ID = pm.post_id
    and p.ID = i.order_id
    and p.post_date BETWEEN '2016-01-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-14 23:59:59'
    and p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
    and p.ID = i.order_id
    and i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
group by
    p.ID
```

but I'm stuck on obtaining `sku` and `product_price` using `product_id` (both values came as NULL), when on phpMyAdmin I will do search by its value I can get SKU and product price `meta_value` as well other values for `meta_key` located in the `wp_postmeta` table.

Based on comments below and helpful directions from an answer I have made `JOIN` version query which works but is slow:

```
select 
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    i.order_item_id,
    max( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id' THEN im.meta_value END ) as product_id,
    max( CASE WHEN imq.meta_key = '_qty' THEN imq.meta_value END ) as qty,
    max( CASE WHEN prm.meta_key = '_sku' THEN prm.meta_value END ) as sku,
    max( CASE WHEN prm.meta_key = '_regular_price' THEN prm.meta_value END ) as product_price
from 
    wp_posts as p
join  
    wp_postmeta as pm
on
    p.ID = pm.post_id
join
    wp_woocommerce_order_items as i
on 
    p.ID = i.order_id
join
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as im
on
    i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
join
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as imq
on
    i.order_item_id = imq.order_item_id
join  
    wp_postmeta as prm
on
    im.meta_value = prm.post_id
where 
    p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    and p.post_date BETWEEN '2016-01-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-14 23:59:59'
    and p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
group by
    p.ID
```

My question is why do I need to create `JOIN` for each `CASE` statement - other way for an example `qty` returns value as NULL.

Comment: Learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have tried JOIN as well but then I need to JOIN multiple times same tables and GoDaddy is dropping connections on that kind of query

Comment: @GordonLinoff Re commas in the `FROM` clause - what I should to use then?

Comment: The comma operator is old school syntax for a JOIN operation. It's good that the old syntax is still supported, because that allows old legacy SQL to run. But SQL in new development should use the `JOIN` keyword in place of the comma. And move the join predicates out of the `WHERE` clause to an appropriate `ON` clause.

Comment: @spencer7593 OK - I have used `JOIN` in place of the comma and got `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` message

Comment: @GordonLinoff  OP updated with `JOIN` version of a query

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for directions - I have updated OP with them. Query works but is slow (12s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - I have ended up removing `CASE`statement and moving towards explicit `JOIN` syntax.

```
select 
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    i.order_item_id,
    im.meta_value as product_id,
    imq.meta_value as qty,
    prm.meta_value as sku,
    prp.meta_value as product_price
from 
    wp_posts as p
join  
    wp_postmeta as pm
on
    p.ID = pm.post_id
join
    wp_woocommerce_order_items as i
on 
    p.ID = i.order_id
join
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as im
on
    i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
join
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as imq
on
    i.order_item_id = imq.order_item_id
join  
    wp_postmeta as prm
on
    im.meta_value = prm.post_id
join  
    wp_postmeta as prp
on
    im.meta_value = prp.post_id
where 
    p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    and p.post_date BETWEEN '2016-01-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-14 23:59:59'
    and p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
    and im.meta_key = '_product_id'
    and imq.meta_key = '_qty'
    and prm.meta_key = '_sku'
    and prp.meta_key = '_regular_price'
group by
    p.ID
```

Thanks to spencer7593 for good directions.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any predicate in the join to `wp_postmeta` (alias `prm` in the query.) So that's a cross join operation. Performing a cross join is valid; but it's unlikely that's the result you want.

Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation. Use the ANSI `JOIN` keyword. And relocate the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an appropriate `ON` clause.

Some of the conditional tests in the `CASE` expression are unnecessary, because they are redundant. They will always evaluate to TRUE.

The query includes this join predicate (in the `WHERE` clause)

```
i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
```

That same condition appears again in the CASE expression:

```
CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id' and i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id THEN
```

There's no need to repeat that condition in the CASE expression, because it's going to evaluate to TRUE for every row that is returned.

```
CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id' THEN
```

---

Given the "missing" join predicate for the join to `wp_postmeta` (aliased as `prm`)... and given the condition we see in the other CASE expressions

```
im.meta_value = prm.post_id
```

We suspect that you want to include that condition as a join predicate.

Absent sample rows, we're just guessing. My guess at what you are trying to achieve, is a result something like this:

```
SELECT p.id as order_id
     , p.post_date
     , i.order_item_id
     , MAX( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id'     THEN im.meta_value  END ) as product_id
     , MAX( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_qty'            THEN im.meta_value  END ) as qty
     , MAX( CASE WHEN prm.meta_key = '_sku'           THEN prm.meta_value END ) as sku
     , MAX( CASE WHEN prm.meta_key = '_regular_price' THEN prm.meta_value END ) as product_price
  FROM wp_posts p
  JOIN wp_postmeta pm
    ON pm.post_id = p.ID
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items i
    ON i.order_id = p.ID
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta im
    ON im.order_item_id = i.order_item_id
  JOIN wp_postmeta as prm
    ON prm.post_id = im.meta_value
 WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
   AND p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
   AND p.post_date >= '2016-01-14'
   AND p.post_date <  '2016-01-15'
 GROUP BY p.ID
```

This doesn't take into account the possibility of "missing" rows from `prm`, perhaps you want to use an outer join operation.

And with `i.order_item_id` in the SELECT list, and the CASE expressions returning values from `im`, it looks like you might want to include `i.order_item_id` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

But again, those are just guesses.

Comment: No clue but `qty` in this case comes as NULL when was present in the original query

Comment: The most likely explanation for `qty` returning NULL is the inner join operation to `prm`. There's no "matching" row in `prm`, with `im.meta_value`. Looks like you only want the join for rows with `_product_id`. Use to separate joins to `_itemmeta`, one to get product_id.  Add another join to get just `_qty.